# Adaptation of argument list by inserting () is deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want

Tags: scala

I have def in a test that gives this warning:

> Warning:(162, 17) Adaptation of argument list by inserting () is
>   deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
>           signature: Function1.apply(v1: T1): R   given arguments:   after adaptation: Function1((): Unit)
>       try testCode()

This def is a helper method to insert some data in a repository and does some cleanup afterwards. This is how it looks:

```
  def withTestData( ... some arguments ) (testCode: Unit => Any): Unit = {   

    // Insert some test data in the repository...                                   
    ...
    ... 

    try testCode() // gives warning
    finally testData.destroy()
  }
```

This is how I use the method:

```
def myTest() {
  withTestData() { _ =>
    assertSomething()
  }
}
```

I am using Scala 2.12. How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: You want `() => Any` instead of `Unit => Any`

Comment: You want `=> Any` instead of `() => Any`

Comment: MCVE: `def f(t: Unit => Any) = t( () )` (try replacing `( () )` by `()` to get the error).